# Cannot post data with query String using httpClient in angular 4

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular4-httpclient

I am trying to post some data and I am passing an access token as query string. I will be getting a blob response from server. I used following code :

```
public issueId(asset: Type): Observable<Blob> {
    let urlSearchParams = new HttpParams().set('access_token', this.cookieService.get('access_token'));
    console.log('Entered DataService issueID');
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/system/identities/issue', asset, {urlSearchParams},{responseType: "blob"});
}
```

I am getting error "Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 4". I am using angular 4. Asset is the body of post request.

Comment: It's basically you are passing more arguments than expected

Comment: ya , but I then how I can reduce the arguments. I need to mention api address, the body, the responsetype and query string as well. Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: You can remove the `{responseType: "blob"}` and handle it once you got the response

Comment: I just added the query string in the api address, now there is no need of param argument.

Answer (score 1):

As per the  [post](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)  documentation , you have to do as below

```
put(url: url, body: data, 
 options: {params: urlSearchParams,responseType: "blob"});
```

aso you need to pass `responsetype` ans `params` as part of options

Answer (score 0):

You are sending multiple optional objects with request. Change your request like this.

```
public issueId(asset: Type): Observable<Blob> {
    let urlSearchParams = new HttpParams().set('access_token', this.cookieService.get('access_token'));
    console.log('Entered DataService issueID');
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/system/identities/issue', asset, { params: urlSearchParams, responseType: "blob"});
}
```